# Excel - How to auto-populate from one sheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the scenario.  For ease, I will use a Calorie log as my example.

Worksheet1 contains all food consumed for an entire day.  Worksheet2 is an index of the foods consumed.

For example, in Worksheet2 I have:

```
A1 Name of Food
B1 Serving Size
C1 Calories
D1 Protein
E1 Carbs
F1 Fat
...
A24 Banana
B24 1 banana
C24 100
D24 5
E24 5
F24 5
```

In Worksheet1 I have what food I ate on any specific day with the totals added up for calorie counting.

What I would like to be able to do, is input the value of the food into A1 in Worksheet1 and have it automatically fill out the information from Worksheet2.

For example, in Worksheet1 I'd like to have:

A1 = Cell Value of Food in Worksheet 2, i.e. A24.

I would then like B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7 to auto-populate with the information from Worksheet2.

I know how to call a value from another spreadsheet, but I don't know how to call a value from another spreadsheet based on a value in worksheet1.

Comment: could you provide some screenshots of your worksheets? it would make alot more sense that way

Comment: maybe [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/637497/excel-2010-how-to-select-or-display-rows-if-column-c-has-specific-values-no-v) can fit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User376123, I have set up an example to accomplish what you want.

I have Sheet1 which contains my list of data:

[image]

In Sheet 2 I have formulas set up to do the math and looking up of what I ate. I input what I ate and the servings of that thing that I ate in columns A and B:

[image]

In order to look up the corresponding values, I use a match and index command:

[image]

Dragging the formula to the right, I populate columns C through G. In H through K I calculate the values of each based on the servings I had:

[image]

Simply drag down the row for the number of values you wish to look up.

I do hope this helps!

(My data is totally accurate :) 12 bananas, 25 cookies, and 10 apples a day)

Comment: That works!  However, I do have one other question to maybe make this more simple.

In an attempt to not flip back and forth between sheets.  Let's say the next day, I ate another apple.  And instead of having to copy/paste information - I could just enter A4 into column A of Sheet2 and it auto-pouplated what I hate from spreadsheet2.  

For example - if I make a call to a spreadsheet I do ='Worksheet2'!A4 ...I want to replace A4 with the value in the A column of spreadsheet1 to save time.  So if I enter C4 into spreadsheet1 it automatically makes ='Worksheet2'!C4

Comment: What is your other question? Can you check that this is the right answer to what you asked too please?